# Update field by @formula in Lotus Notes form in read mode

Tags: lotus-notes, formula, lotus

I have computed field in Lotus Notes form (client not web). I would like to show in this field how many days left from specific date till now. I've used @formula and everything is o.k. except one thing, I need to toggle form from read to edit mode and save it otherwise value in the field isn't updating and keep showing old value. How can I perform this task without using an agent? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the field type to Computed for Display.

And if you need to show that same value in a view column, you can copy the field formula to the column formula.

Comment: Thank you, you were right but I also have had to delete all old forms created and stored in db because only new forms work as needed.

Comment: Next time you (or anyone else) runs into this: you didn't have to delete the documents.  You could have just run a one-line agent against those old documents to delete the previously stored item values from those documents. The agent syntax would be FIELD yourComputedFieldName := @DeleteField;  Once the stored items are removed from the documents, the Computed for Display field on the form would work for all documents.